# Properties in Spring, accessing within Java app

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a properties set like so :

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="file:${catalina.home}/conf/my.properties"
        ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

they are then referenced in app context (specifically app.email) like so :

```
<bean id="alertMailMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
  <property name="to">
    <value>${app.email}</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

However when I try to access that property within an actual pojo, not a spring bean  - actually a pojo annotated as a hibernate entity (not the alertMailMessage bean) it is coming back as null ?

```
@Value("${app.email}")
private String defaultEmailAddress;
```

I want to use the value of property setting "app.email" elsewhere, other than alertMailMessage, whats the best way ? (alertMailMessage is working fine btw)

Comment: How are you creating the bean that contains `defaultEmailAddress`?  If it is created manually using `new`, then spring has no way of intercepting that and applying the `@Value` annotation.

Comment: @beny23 So I need to create a spring bean containing all the properties I want to access, then reference that in my non-spring beans ? Or make my hibernate entities spring beans  - which sounds painful ?

Comment: I don't think making your hibernate entities spring beans will be the answer because, it'll be hibernate that'll instantiate the entities on lookup, so spring won't have any control over hibernate instantiated entities without some customisation of hibernate.  However, I'm not sure why you would want the "defaultEmailAddress" (a system-wide setting) in an entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set it in a hibernate entity, because hibernate entities are not managed by spring.

Use the `@Value` annotation in your spring service which creates the hibernate entity, and set it manually if needed. But it looks odd to store a default value in the database, so reconsider that.

As a sidenote: you *can* have hibernate entities managed by spring if using aspectJ and `@Configurable`, but that may complicate things unnecessarily.

Comment: Why is ut odd ? If there is no data associated with the field by the business, it should have a default value, that default value is context/deployment dependent ... I will create a spring bean to contain it then reference that. More reasonable ?

Comment: yes, you can only have it in a spring bean. And I said it's odd, because if it's a default, it will be the same for all records. And you already have it as config property. But if it's fine in your case, go ahead

Comment: Maybe it is weird requirement, but it should be the same for all records unless the business overrides its. Thanks.